# Symfony two submit events in one form

Tags: forms, symfony, filter, submit, dropdown

I'd like to add an entity type to my form, but it should be filtered by several elements. 
Therefore I created a filter form which is on top of the page:
[image]

When clicking "Apply Filter" I'd like the dropdown **Select Document** be filtered by all the selected data. After then selecting some of the documents from the list, I'd like to again submit the form and **deactivate** all of the selected documents.

I already tried different ways of handling this but nothing has worked so far.

1. I haven't figured out yet how to filter my dropdown after submitting the filterform. I tried different EventListeners and then using a query builder or retrieving the data from my controller and passing it to a query builder. But either I did it wrong, or it is the wrong way to do it. (The filter itself works!)

Any guide/advice would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need this :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

have you followed that guide?

Anyway you can also split filters and select list into two independent forms, so once filters are applied, there could be an ajax call which returns view with document select list, then once user submits the choice you read ids of documents in seperate action from the request and then you deactivate them

Comment: Thanks @Markownikow ! I actually have already tried following that guide but maybe I didn't understand how to apply it on my situation because it didn't help.. Could you guide me a little bit for that, or are you not familiar?
I'll try your advice with ajax, though! I would create one form in my filter controller and the other in my deactivation controller, did I understand that correctly? And how would the ajax call look like?